# Parameter type checking different in call signature vs function type expression

Tags: typescript

I noticed a difference in how the arguments are type-checked between the different syntax of function types in TypeScript.

```
type TypeA = {
  callback(value?: string): void,
}

type TypeB = {
  callback: (value?: string) => void,
}

function foo (value: string) {}

const a: TypeA = {
 // No error
 callback: foo,
}

// Property 'callback' is missing in type '{}'
// but required in type 'TypeA'
const a2: TypeA = {
}

const b: TypeB = {
  // Type '(value: string) => void' is not assignable to
  // type '(value?: string | undefined) => void'.
  callback: foo,
}
```

Here's the [typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEEEoF4oG8BQUoGMCGANgQEZ44DWAFAG6ECuEA-AFxQDOwATgJYB2A5gEpW1APbcAJgBoMAXwwZQkWPABCKdFlyESZcqxr0mrDjwGCUAPihjJM+RgBmdXjmDdRvKI9GiohggYTLj4hdAccTw4oPFY4SCRUTG0iUgpWH1F7BUjeaLwAJjj4RM0IqOAoYmLIdSStfFS9DN9soA)

The call signature function type happily accepts a function with param `value: string`, while the function type expression complaints that it is not exactly `value: string | undefined`.
I would've expected a type error in both the cases.

Why is the call signature syntax more relaxed about the argument type?

Comment: Also check the section about methods here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66410115/difference-between-variance-covariance-contravariance-and-bivariance-in-typesc

Comment: Thanks, @TobiasS. that explains it clearly!